# css selector for table with scroll

Tags: css, angular, sass, scroll

I have a table in html page,
it can contain some or many records, I want to apply specific css to the table, only when there is a scroll on the table, when there are some records and there is no scroll I don't want this css definition to affect the table.
How can I do it?

```
table **here I need the selector** thead {
     width: calc( 100% - .5em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, 
      remove it from thead width */
}
```

Comment: please share your code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ViewChild` ref to the table and check if scroll is visible in `ngClass` if scroll is exist then the class will be added to the table :

```
<table #table [ngClass]="{'visibleScroll': table.scrollHeight > table.clientHeight }"></table>
```

then add your class in css style sheet:

```
.visibleScroll{
//your style css
}
```